# Video Streaming: WebRTC vs. VLC vs. Other?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying to create a media streaming app and am contemplating over which method of streaming video from a local directory on a PC. I am considering using WebRTC through HTML5 and Javascript. This would be really cool to do, I understand WebRTC is meant for two way channels, but it would be interesting to see how it would fair in a one way stream of local media content. However, I am looking for input on this. Would it be significantly slower than VLC streaming or some other form of streaming? Could someone point me in the right direction if WebRTC is a bad idea?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq/ <-- Please read that. This is a very subjective question and Stack Overflow is not meant for this type of question.

Comment: You should ask this in http://avp.stackexchange.com

Comment: People are too eager to close questions. This is a fine question, on a topic of direct interest to many programmers, capable of an objective answer, and very much in the tradition of good SO questions. (It could perhaps use some editing to make it a bit more specific, but suggesting that is better than closing it.) In contrast, avp.stackexchange.com is a poor choice for this.

Comment: Agree with @Ken Smith. The question is very useful. When a question "which is better", it doesn't mean we care about a simple answer. And I believe people would like to know under which situations use which method, which is very useful.